# How can I use ANAF (accepts nested attr for) on a Form Object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, attributes, nested

So far I have been using a Form Object as described in https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit:

```
class ProfileForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  etc
end

simple_form_for(@profile_form)
```

But I would like to now use fields_for photos where Profile has many photos. How can I add ANAF to ProfileForm form for photos instead of Profile.

Comment: Accepted Nested Attributes For

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no such acronym :)